# R: How to use group_by() to calculate the proportion of a variable within another variable?

Tags: r, variables, group-by, pipe, dplyr

I want to use group_by to display the proportion of each education attainment (variable: `edattain`) within variable: `sex`.

So far I have calculated the proportions of `edattain` below:

```
india04_new4 %>%
mutate(tot = sum(perwt, na.rm = T)) %>%
group_by(edattain) %>%
summarise(share = sum(perwt, na.rm = T)/first(tot))
```

How can I display the proportions within the variable: `sex`?

Comment: Please add data using `dput` and show the expected output for the same. Read about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).

Comment: The dataset is too large to use dput(), sex variable has two values: male/female, eddattain has multiple values: < primary/primary/secondary/university/Unknown . perwt is a variable that represents the # of individuals that are represented by the datapoint in a population.

Comment: You don't need to share the entire data, a minimal example with 5-10 rows which shows various columns and it's type along with expected output is enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following :

```
result <- india04_new4 %>%
            group_by(sex, edattain) %>%
            summarise(share = sum(perwt, na.rm = TRUE)) %>%
            mutate(share = share/sum(share))
```